# Get initial value of entity in FormExtension

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4, symfony-forms

In my update form, I want to add a data attribute on the inputs that will contains the initial value of the entity. This way, I will be able to highlight the input when the user will modify it.

In the end, only the input modified by the users will be highlighted.

I want to use this only in update, not in creation.

To do so, I created a form extension like this:

```
class IFormTypeExtension extends AbstractTypeExtension
{
...

public static function getExtendedTypes()
{
    //I want to be able to extend any form type
    return [FormType::class];
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'is_iform' => false,
        'is_iform_modification' => function (Options $options) {
            return $options['is_iform'] ? null : false;
        },
    ]);
    $resolver->setAllowedTypes('is_iform', 'bool');
    $resolver->setAllowedTypes('is_iform_modification', ['bool', 'null']);
}

public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    if (!$options['is_iform'] && !$this->isParentIForm($form)) {
        return;
    }

    //We need to add the original value in the input as data-attributes
    if (is_string($form->getViewData()) || is_int($form->getViewData())) {
        $originValue = $form->getViewData();
    } elseif (is_array($form->getViewData())) {
        if (is_object($form->getNormData())) {
            $originValue = implode('###', array_keys($form->getViewData()));
        } elseif (is_array($form->getNormData()) && count($form->getNormData()) > 0 && is_object($form->getNormData()[0])) {
            $originValue = implode('###', array_keys($form->getViewData()));
        } else {
            $originValue = implode('###', $form->getViewData());
        }
    } else {
        //There's no value yet
        $originValue = '';
    }

    $view->vars['attr'] = array_merge($view->vars['attr'], ['data-orig-value' => $originValue]);
}

private function isParentIForm(FormInterface $form)
{
    if (null === $form->getParent()) {
        return $form->getConfig()->getOption('is_iform');
    }

    return $this->isParentIForm($form->getParent());
}
}
```

As you can see in the buildView method, I get the originValue from the ViewData.

In a lot of cases, this works well.

But if I have any validation error in my form OR if I reload my form through AJAX, the `ViewData` contains the new information and not the values of the entity I want to update.

How can I get the values of the original entity?

1. I don't want to make a DB request in here.
2. I think I can use the `FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA` event, then save the entity values in session and use these in the `buildView`.
3. I could also give a new Option in my OptionResolver to ask for the initial entity.
4. Is it possible to have the original data of the entity directly form the `buildView`? (If I'm not wrong, this means the form before we call the `handleRequest` method).

Someone wanted to have an example with a controller. I don't think it's really interresting, because with the FormExtension, the code will be added automatically. But anyway, here is how I create a form in my controller :

```
$form = $this->createForm(CustomerType::class, $customer)->handleRequest($request);
```

And in the CustomerType, I will add the 'is_iform' key with configureOptions() :

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        "translation_domain" => "customer",
        "data_class" => Customer::class,
        'is_iform' => true //This line will activate the extension
    ]);
}
```

Comment: can you show controller code where you create the form and such?

Comment: There's nothing really interesting in the controller, because I create a normal Form there. I will edit my question anyway

Comment: Instead trying to access the the default value from the form object in the builder. Why not use the options for the 'selected' value when creating the form? `$this->createForm(BlaType::class, $bla, ['bla' => $bla->property])` Your extension can then just trigger if option is not null and do simple comparisons without having to do weird things. As a bonus would also make it more dynamic/reuseable.

Comment: Yes, it's also a possibility. The problem with this is that I will have to change the already created forms.
In your example, I would like to have access to the $bla values, it's the simpliest way to do it.
But I can't just give a single property because I want this extension looking for any property of the entity, so it's not a "simpe comparison" :)

Comment: so, as far as I can tell, your problem seems to be, that after a submit, the original values on your entity are gone, correct? You have to be aware, that to retrieve the `$customer` in the first place requires a db request. As far as I can tell the two solutions I would consider are: 1. using the entity manager (or more precisely the unit of work) to reset the entity (there is a snapshot) or 2. use a dto instead, which can be easily created, but of course after validation, you would have to apply the changes to your entity object. After 1./2. you can just create a new form with `createForm`

Comment: that way, also `is_iform` would be unnecessary, because the extensions logic would be unnecessary in the first place, I guess.

Comment: After a submit, the original values let place to the submitted one. And doing so, when I get the data-orig-value, they're the submitted ones.
In fact, in the controller, I already do a db request to get the values (even on submit, through a ParamConverter).
The problem doing a DB request is that, because of the extension is linked to each type of form, I would do a request per input, and that is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I managed to make it work BUT I'm not fully convinced by what I did.

It was not possible to get the original data from the form OR add a new property (the form is read only in the form extension).

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) {
            $form = $event->getForm();
            if ('_token' === $form->getName()) {
                return;
            }

            $data = $event->getData();
            $this->session->set('iform_'.$form->getName(), is_object($data) ? clone $data : $data);
        }
    );
}
```

What I do here, is simply register the form values by its name in the session.
If it's an object, I need to clone it, because the form will modify it later in the process and I want to work with the original state of the form.

```
public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults([
        'is_iform' => false,
        'is_iform_modification' => function (Options $options) {
            return $options['is_iform'] ? null : false;
        },
    ]);
    $resolver->setAllowedTypes('is_iform', 'bool');
    $resolver->setAllowedTypes('is_iform_modification', ['bool', 'null']);
}
```

The configure options did not change.
And then, depending on the value type, I create my "data-orig-value" :

```
public function buildView(FormView $view, FormInterface $form, array $options)
{
    if (!$options['is_iform'] && !$this->isParentIForm($form)) {
        return;
    }

    $propertyValue = $this->session->get('iform_'.$form->getName());
    $originValue = '';

    try {
        if (null !== $propertyValue) {
            //We need to add the original value in the input as data-attributes
            if (is_bool($propertyValue)) {
                $originValue = $propertyValue ? 1 : 0;
            } elseif (is_string($propertyValue) || is_int($propertyValue)) {
                $originValue = $propertyValue;
            } elseif (is_array($propertyValue) || $propertyValue instanceof Collection) {
                if (is_object($propertyValue)) {
                    $originValue = implode('###', array_map(function ($object) {
                        return $object->getId();
                    }, $propertyValue->toArray()));
                } elseif (is_array($propertyValue) && count($propertyValue) > 0 && is_object(array_values($propertyValue)[0])) {
                    $originValue = implode('###', array_map(function ($object) {
                        return $object->getId();
                    }, $propertyValue));
                } else {
                    $originValue = implode('###', $propertyValue);
                }
            } elseif ($propertyValue instanceof DateTimeInterface) {
                $originValue = \IntlDateFormatter::formatObject($propertyValue, $form->getConfig()->getOption('format', 'dd/mm/yyyy'));
            } elseif (is_object($propertyValue)) {
                $originValue = $propertyValue->getId();
            } else {
                $originValue = $propertyValue;
            }
        }
    } catch (NoSuchPropertyException $e) {
        if (null !== $propertyValue = $this->session->get('iform_'.$form->getName())) {
            $originValue = $propertyValue;
            $this->session->remove('iform_'.$form->getName());
        } else {
            $originValue = '';
        }
    } finally {
        //We remove the value from the session, to not overload the memory
        $this->session->remove('iform_'.$form->getName());
    }

    $view->vars['attr'] = array_merge($view->vars['attr'], ['data-orig-value' => $originValue]);
}

private function isParentIForm(FormInterface $form)
{
    if (null === $form->getParent()) {
        return $form->getConfig()->getOption('is_iform');
    }

    return $this->isParentIForm($form->getParent());
}
```

Maybe the code sample will help anyone !
If anyone have a better option, don't hesitate to post it !

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an opinionated answer. There also might be better approaches.
I'm not a big fan of your form extension, since it's really convoluted and unclear what's happening, at least to my eyes.

What I'm proposing: When the form submit happened, in your controller you should do the following

```
// ((*)) maybe store customer, see below
$form = $this->createForm(CustomerType::class, $customer);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
   // easy case, you got this.
   $em->flush();

   return $this->redirect(); // or another response

} elseif($form->isSubmitted()) {

   // form was submitted with errors, have to refresh entity!

   // REFRESH - see discussion below for alternatives
   $em->refresh($customer);

   // then create form again with original values:
   $form = $this->createForm(CustomerType::class, $customer); 
}
// other stuff
return $this->render(..., ['form' => $form->createView(), ...]);
```

so, essentially, when the form validation fails, you refresh the entity and recreate the form, avoiding the problem with the changed state of your entity. I believe this approach ultimately is easier then hacking the form to magically not update values or re-set older values.

Now the question remains: how to refresh an entity? Simplest approach: reload from database:

```
$em->refresh($customer); // easiest approach, will likely run another query.
```

Alternatives:

1. Instead of giving `$customer` to the form, you create a customer DTO that contains the same values but on change doesn't automatically change the original object. If the form validation fails, you can just re-generate the DTO.
2. Instead of `refresh($customer)`, which will most likely run another query (except maybe not, if you have a cache), you could cache the customer yourself via a [`DefaultCacheEntityHydrator`](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Cache/DefaultEntityHydrator.php), you would have to create your own [EntityCacheKey](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Cache/EntityCacheKey.php) object (not really hard), generate a cache entry (`DefaultCacheEntityHydrator::buildCacheEntry()` at the `((*))` above) and restore the entry for when you need to restore it. Disclaimer: I don't know if/how this works with collections (i.e. collection properties, the entity might have).

That being said ... if you really really want a form extension for whatever reason, you might want to form event with a PRE_SET_DATA handler that stores the data in the form type object, then on buildView uses those values. I wouldn't store something in the session for I don't see the necessity ... your aversion to db queries is baffling though, if that's your main reason for all the shenanigans

Comment: Thanks for this interesting answer !
Unfortunately, this won't work in some cases : when I need to reload my form with AJAX to add/remove fields depending on what the user selected (there's some select/option that change the form depending on the selected option).

Another thing that bother me with what you propose is that, if the user got an invalid form, we create another form. And so, the validation messages and the user inputs are removed.

Comment: that's a fair point. have you considered that instead of sending the form back to the frontend to just send the error messages and make some frontend magic?

Comment: Yeah, I considered it tbh, but I think it will be easier to use the FormExtension, I'm quite sure there's a way to do it ! I just need to find how ! Haha

Comment: as suggested ... if you need form extension, use pre_set_data event handler to store data in some new form property and buildView to rewrite the values from those ... maybe ... depends on the form really though ;O/